# Как реализовать менеджер передачи данных по tcp?

Tags: tcp-ip, java, многопоточность

Добрый день стоит задача, реализовать менеджер который общается с сервером через tcp.
тут проблем нет, есть другая проблема. Менеджер должен работать в другом потоке. И так, есть 2 потока, поток main, и поток будем называть его manager. Поток main создает 2 поток (manager), оо (мэйн) управляет 2 потоком, и получает от него инфу.

У manager'a есть несколько функций:

- connect  - соединение с сервером
- call - позвонить абоненту (к примеру)
- waitEvent - получение event'a из очереди у manager'a ( как вы наверно поняли manager получает от сервера ответы и складывает их в очередь)
- hangDown - положить трубку
- close - разорвать соединение с сервером.
  примерный алгоритм основного потока (main):

.

```
manager.connect();
try{
  manager.call();
  EventData eventData;
  while((eventData = manager.waitEvent()) != null) {
    // к примеру логируем eventDat'у
  }
} finally {
  manager.close();
}
```

Вопрос, точнее крик души, я хз как реализовать manager, имеется ввиду с точки зрения потоков, я могу без проблем отправлять данные на сервер, и получать ответы и складывать их в очередь. Но начитавшись статей, хз как вызывать несколько разных функций из другого потока. Везде что читал писалось, что надо сделать класс унаследованый к примеру от Thread, переопределить в нем функцию run - эта функция и будет крутиться в новом потоке.
А мне надо вызвать несколько функций ( поясню, функции просто выполняют запрос на сервер (отсулку нескольких байт инфы) и все) + постоянно обрабатывать ответы от сервера (получить несколько строк от сервера и складировать их в очередь)...

По чесноку не понятно вообще  как реализовать...

p.s. не прошу куски кода или чего то подобного, прошу лишь помочь с идеей по реализации.
p.p.s задачу надо сдавать еще вчера, а так получилось что не работал в java  ни с потоками ни с tcp.
p.p.p.s Заранее благодарен.

Comment: @Alexander Popov, на самом деле нельзя непосредственно вызывать функции другого потока. Только своего. 

Один поток может лишь создать другой (именно вызвав метод Thread.run), а затем потоки обмениваются данными через общую память.

Если одна и та же функция (в терминологии Java (и вообще ООП) метод) вызвана из разных потоков, то на самом деле это будут разные ее активации (каждая со своим стеком и т.п.).

--

Т.е. Вам нужно запустить manager как отдельный поток, а вот его методы, вызываемые из других потоков,  должны обеспечивать  согласованный обмен данными между очередями.

Answer (score 1):

Исходим из того, что один поток может выполнять в единицу времени какую-то одну последовательность команд. В вашей терминологии это означает, что один поток может выполнять одновременно только одну функцию.

Т.к. вы хотите выполнять несколько разных функций, то вижу два подхода:

1. Использовать очередь для разделения логики генерации задачи и выполнения (см. [produce-consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem)). Все лучае большого кол-ва задач в очереди вы сможете просто увеличить кол-во потребляющих потоков. Правда все еще остается проблема приема сообщений от удаленного сервера. Для этого вам все-равно понадобится как минимум один отдельный поток.
2. Использовать множество потоков для выполнения ваших "функций" без использования очередей (напрмер создавать поток на каждую задачу).

Все это довольно легко делается с помощью Executor-фреймворка (см. [Java Tutorials: Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html)).